# Apache config precendence

Tags: httpd.conf

If I set a configuration option in `httpd.conf` which is *not* used again in any of our vhosts, will it be in effect for each of the vhosts or will each one need to have the option set?

Specifically, I want to set the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` options. Sadly, we have far more vhost configurations than is sane so setting this option in each file and validating would be a hassle in the time it needs to be deployed (don't get me started on configuration management). So, if I set it in `httpd.conf` and make sure it is not in any of the vhost configs, will it apply to every vhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Apache doumentation, configuration sections are merged in in the following order:

1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) 
      and .htaccess done simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed,
      overriding `<Directory>`)
2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory "~">`)
3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously
5. `<If>`

> *Some important remarks:*
>
> - Apart from `<Directory>`, within each group the sections are processed in the order they appear in the configuration files. For example, a request for /foo will match `<Location "/foo/bar">` and `<Location "/foo">` (group 4 in this case): both sections will be evaluated but in the order they appear in the configuration files.
> - `<Directory>` (group 1 above) is processed in the order shortest directory component to longest. For example, `<Directory "/var/web/dir">` will be processed before `<Directory "/var/web/dir/subdir">`.
> - If multiple `<Directory>` sections apply to the same directory they are processed in the configuration file order.
> - Configurations included via the Include directive will be treated as if they were inside the including file at the location of the Include directive.
> - Sections inside `<VirtualHost>` sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.
> - When the request is served by mod_proxy, the  container takes the place of the `<Directory>` container in the processing order.

For example, the following will be applied in the order A > B  > C > D > E:

```
<Location "/">
    E
</Location>

<Files "f.html">
    D
</Files>

<VirtualHost *>
    <Directory "/a/b">
        B
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<DirectoryMatch "^.*b$">
    C
</DirectoryMatch>

<Directory "/a/b">
    A
</Directory>
```

More information can be found in the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html

#### Edit:

Directives like `<Directory>`, `<DirectoryMatch>`, `<Files>`, `<FilesMatch>`, `<Location>`, `<LocationMatch>`, and `<VirtualHost>` simply limit the scope of the directives they enclose, so applying an `<IfModule>` directive to the global area of the file will apply it globally.

If you are trying to override `mod_rewrite`, you may consider leveraging a `RewriteOptions` directive set to `InheritDown`. This will cause all child configurations to inherit the settings from the parent scope and is equivalent to putting `RewriteOptions Inherit` in each child scope.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteOptions InheritDown
    RewriteLog [some setting here]
    RewriteLogLevel [somesettinghere]
</IfModule>
```

Placing this globally would apply your logging options to every child scope.

Comment: Thank you. I read this but I'm still not sure about the application of the option. If I add an `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` section at the top level of `httpd.conf`, will it apply to all VirtualHosts or just the root of the server?

Comment: @theillien Updated answer to account for your comment here.